# How to handle error message from php to jQuery ajax error handler?

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling

In the stub code below, when the error: method is invoked, the "errorThrown" variable just returns "object Object".

How can I get it to print out the actual text?

```
jQuery.ajax
({
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    url: myURL,

    success: function(data)
    {       
        if(data['response'] === undefined){
            this.error('No data returned');
        }

        //success code goes here                        
    },

    error: function(errorThrown)
    {
        result += errorThrown;
alert('The error was: '+errorThrown);
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: use a Javascript Debugger and set a breakpoint in the error function. Then inspect the object coming back to see where the error text you want to display is located.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error function receives three arguments. The first is a jQueryXmlHttpRequest Object, the second and third are probably useful to you:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
     alert('Error Message: '+textStatus);
     alert('HTTP Error: '+errorThrown);
}
```

Comment: `errorThrown.name`, `errorThrown.message`, `errorThrown.stack` hold the error strings. `alert(errorThrown.stack)` should be enough to track down issues that may surface.

Comment: `errorThrown` is just a string. then how could we get stack from `errorThrown`.

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter passed to the jQuery ajax error function is of type jqXHR (XMLHttpRequest in jQuery 1.4.x.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

The response will be contained in the responseText property:

```
error: function(errorThrown)
{
    result += errorThrown.responseText;
    alert('The error was: '+errorThrown.responseText);
    return;
}
```